# How to collect JVM metrics of a running java-application from the command line?

Tags: java

Can someone tell me how to collect the JVM-metrics of interest for a running java application from the command line. For example, how to get metrics:

```
   JVM Memory HeapMemoryUsage.max           jmx["java.lang:type=Memory",HeapMemoryUsage.max] 

   JVM ClassLoading TotalLoadedClassCount   jmx["java.lang:type=ClassLoading",TotalLoadedClassCount]

   JVM ClassLoading UnloadedClassCount      jmx["java.lang:type=ClassLoading",UnloadedClassCount]
```

and so on ?

Is there any console utility for collecting them? Please describe an example for it.